# Splitting a sentence into two halves

Tags: python

I have the following structure of sentences:

```
sent = '(1 (2(2 The) (2 Rock)) (2(2 is) (2 big)) )'
```

where numbers mean sentiment assessment, and the other part in brackets is a word.
What I want to do: is to represent sentence as a tree (each parent has maximum 2 children). For this I need a function, that splits a sentence into halves.

I came up with the following solution:

```
def sent_div(sent):
    temp_ind = []
    finish_ind = []
    slash = 0
    back_slash = 0
    for i in range(1,len(sent)):  
        if sent[i] == '(':
            slash +=1
            temp_ind.append(i)
        elif sent[i] == ')':
            back_slash +=1
            finish_ind.append(i)

        if slash == back_slash and slash != 0:
            left = sent[min(temp_ind):i+1]
            break


    temp_ind = []
    slash = 0
    back_slash = 0 
    for i in range(max(finish_ind) + 1,len(sent)):  
        if sent[i] == '(':
            slash +=1
            temp_ind.append(i)
        elif sent[i] == ')':
            back_slash +=1
            #finish_ind.append(i)

        if slash == back_slash and slash != 0:
            right = sent[min(temp_ind):i+1]
            break


    return left,right
```

The result is:

```
left,right = sent_div(sent)

print(left)
'(2(2 The) (2 Rock))' 

print(right)
'(2(2 is) (2 big))')

sent_div(right)
('(2 is)', '(2 big)')
```

But it looks ugly. Can you suggest any improvements to my code?

Comment: Does the structure of your string adhere to the "max 2 children" rule, ie. in any set of parentheses, are there no more than two next-level sets of parentheses? Or is your example just accidentally like that?

Comment: Smells like a recursion coming on here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a stack

```
def sent_div(string):
  " Partitions based upon finding balanced nested parens "
  def partition(s):
      " Helper function - uses stack to detect balance parens"
      stack = []
      for i, c in enumerate(s):
          if c == '(':
              stack.append(i)
          elif c == ')':
            if len(stack)==1:
              start = stack.pop()
              return i+1, s[start: i+1]
            elif stack:
              stack.pop()

  i, left = partition(string[1:])
  _, right = partition(string[i:])
  return left, right
```

**Test**

```
left, right = sent_div(sent)
print(left)             # (2(2 The) (2 Rock))
print(right)            # (2(2 is) (2 big))
print(sent_div(right))  # '(2 is)', '(2 big)')
```

**Refactor to not use stack**

Following  Błotosmętek suggestion, we get the following for sent_div.

```
def sent_div(string):
  " Partitions based upon finding balanced nested parens "
  def partition(s):
      " Helper function - uses stack to detect balance parens"
      level, start = 0, -1
      for i, c in enumerate(s):
          if c == '(':
              if level == 0:
                start = i
              level += 1
          elif c == ')':
            if level == 1:
              return i+1, s[start: i+1]
            elif level > 0:
              level -= 1
```

Comment: Instead of stack you could just use an int describing level of nesting. Replace `stack.append(i)` with `level+=1` and `stack.pop()` with `level-=1`, and return on `level==0`.

Comment: @Błotosmętek--thanks for the suggestion.  Updated answer with your comment as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) library and [backreferences](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-regular-expression-back-references-works-in-Python) to turn your string into nested tuples by inserting commas in the right places and evaluating it.

### Backreferences

Backreferences allow us to reference matched groups of a regex expression (the parts which are enclosed in `(...)`) within the replacement string. This allows us to insert characters in specific places of your string.

The following code will insert a comma after every number:

```
find_this = "([0-9]+)"
replacement = r"\1,"
string = "123 456 789"

print(re.sub(find_this, replacement, string))
```

and prints:

```
123, 456, 789,
```

To find a number with a regex string, `r"[0-9]+"` would be enough, but we add the brackets `r"([0-9]+)"` to define the matched string as the first group. In our replacement string `r"\1,"`, we can now reference the group with `\1` and add a comma to the end. That way, the matched number will be replaced with itself plus a trailing comma.

The number `1` here refers to the first matched group within our `find_this` string. If there were more than one group in `find_this`, we could reference it with `\2`.

The replacement string contains the escape character `\`. We therefore have to mark the string as a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), because in raw strings, `\` is interpreted as a normal character.

### Turning your string into tuples

Now we can do the following:

1. insert commas after all numbers

   ```
   s = re.sub("([0-9]+)",r"\1,", s)
   ```
2. insert commas between brackets like these `)(`

   ```
   s = re.sub(r"\)\s*\(", "),(", s)
   ```
3. enclose text in `"..."`

   ```
   s = re.sub("([a-zA-Z])", r'"\1"', s)
   ```

   Notice that we used single quotes `'...'` for the replacement string this time, because it allows us to use double quotes within the string itself.

Now your string looks like a valid python expression:

```
'(1, (2,(2, "The"),(2, "Rock")),(2,(2, "is"),(2, "big")) )'
```

To evaluate it, we can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
t = eval(s)
print(t)

# left part
print(t[1])

# right part
print(t[2])
```

which prints

```
(1, (2, (2, 'The'), (2, 'Rock')), (2, (2, 'is'), (2, 'big')))
(2, (2, 'The'), (2, 'Rock'))
(2, (2, 'is'), (2, 'big'))
```

Here is the full code:

```
import re

s = '(1 (2(2 The) (2 Rock)) (2(2 is) (2 big)) )'

s = re.sub("([0-9]+)", r"\1,", s)
s = re.sub(r"\)\s*\(", "),(", s)
s = re.sub("([a-zA-Z]+)", r'"\1"', s)

t = eval(s)

print(t)
print(t[1])
print(t[2])
```

Comment: Step 4 (enclose numbers in int()) is unnecessary.